# When managing IBM Bluemix via the command line, how do I configure AutoScaling?

Tags: ibm-cloud, autoscaling, cloud-foundry

I'm new to BlueMix and I'm integrating it with our CI/CD pipeline.

I've found the [documentation on how to create Auto-Scaling groups for apps](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/?cm_mc_uid=41634981797514504358760&cm_mc_sid_50200000=#services/Auto-Scaling/index.html#autoscaling), however, this does not appear to describe how to achieve this via the CLI.

I'm assuming that I need to pass some JSON to the "cf" command at creation time, however, I can't find an example of this anywhere either - does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide,

Matt

**EDIT:** This is possible, you just need to use the Bluemix CLI wrapper around the Cloudfoundary CLI: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/plugins/auto-scaling/index.html

Comment: Bluemix welcomes suggestions for enhancements to the platform or its services. You can submit those suggestions here: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#idea

Comment: Thanks, I've created http://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas/suggestions/11390832-allow-setting-of-autoscaling-policy-in-an-automate to track this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the link you provided in the original question, I think the question is related Bluemix Auto-Scaling service.

Definitely, cf cli won't support serivice setting, but Bluemix Auto-Scaling service will provide cli support through Bluemix CLI & Bluemix Auto-Scaling CLI plugin.

With the Auto-Scaling CLI, you can create/attach/view policy and check scaling history.
Check the details with Auto-Scaling CLI with
http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/plugins/auto-scaling/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot adjust settings for this service via the command line. You can add this service to an application via the CLI but then need to use the admin UI to change settings/create a policy, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's a real shame as it introduces a manual step to what could otherwise easily be a fully automated process for app deployment.

I've created an "idea" (see above) and hopefully this will be implemented soon! :)